# How to implement selenium to run in headless mode in linux cloud

Tags: selenium, google-chrome-headless, xvfb

When I use `WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();` to run selenium test cases in headless mode on Windows machine then it works fine. But it doesn't work on Linux cloud.
Do I need xvfb frame buffer, sample code and steps to implement this will be really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

first install xvfb with below command

apt-get install xvfb firefox

Now run your test file using xvfb as

xvfb-run ruby test.rb